# Editing an object via belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many, belongs-to

So I'm trying to edit only the first Post entry when i edit my Thread object.

Here's my setup:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :posts_attributes

has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
end
```

---

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, 

belongs_to :discussion
end
```

---

```
<%= provide(:title, "Edit Discussion")%>
<%= form_for(@thread) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, size: 60 %>

    <%= f.fields_for :posts do |builder| %>

        <%= builder.label :content %>
        <%= builder.text_area :content, :size => "60x15" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Edit Thread" %>
<% end %>
```

If i run this code as is then I get a page where I am able to edit all the posts, I imagine because :posts draws from an association. But I only want the first post

Then if i change the :posts to @discussion.posts.at(0) to get the first post, then I can proceed to the edit page... and the form_for displays correctly however on firing update, it says that I can't edit the protected attribute :posts...  any ideas on how to only show & edit the first post?

Comment: would it help to add attr_accessible :posts?

Comment: What if you try this
    <%= f.fields_for :posts, @thread.posts.first do |builder| %>

Comment: @randomtaiwanese Didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: Wooooo! it worked! Thanks az7ar.